# Exception in multi-Task WCF channel usage (ems)

Tags: c#, wcf, task, ems

I receive an exception of type

> Exception receiving EMS message: The service did not respond.
>   When calling the code below from more than one task.

```
Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
{ 
        var service = CreateChannel();                                           
        try
        {
              return service.GetStuff(string blah);
        }
        finally
        {
               var channel = ((IClientChannel)service);
               try
               {
                    channel.Close();
               }
               catch
               {
                    channel.Abort();
               }
         }
 });
private IService CreateChannel()
{
    lock (_channelFactory)
    {
        return _channelFactory.CreateChannel();
    }            
}
```

If i remove the Channel.Close() there is no exception.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Self Answer**

Updating my tibco.ems.wcf assembly fixed this.